# Why doesn't my page get refreshed after login in to facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, login-script

I have been trying add facebook login to my page. I have facebook login button placed on my page using following script:

```
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        FB.init({ 
            appId:'<?php echo APP_ID;?>', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
        });
    </script>
    <fb:login-button perms="email,user_checkins">
        Login with Facebook
    </fb:login-button>
```

It shows the login button too. while clicking it opens the login screen of facebook too.

after making successfull login the popup box just closes without refreshing the parent page.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not asking the page to refresh after a successful login:

```
// whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

See the [PHP-SDK example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) for more information.

Comment: I found ur Link useful for me as i am even working in php. it was gr8 +1 for link... but got confused abt the above script. where do i add it?

Comment: @KoolKabin: Under your `init` function, it doesn't really matter since it's just attaching a listener

Comment: I found your script useful but after i add this code , my page keeps on refreshing . What could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Two Great Solution

1. `// whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page`

   ```
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
     window.location.reload();
   });`
   ```
2. `<fb:login-button onlogin="LoginFunction()" perms="email,user_likes,user_photos">CONNECT Bla Bla</fb:login-button>`

When the user Login we call the function `LoginFunction()` and then we can do whatever such as refresh or redirect the user.